# Deciding Convergence of the following improper integral of $e^{3x}$

Tags: calculus

Let's consider the following improper integral:

$$\int_4^\infty e^{3x}dx$$

I was thinking that the integral would converge when compared to $e^x$. Why does this integral diverge? Do you compare it to $e^x$?

Comment: You can compare to $1$, or $e^x$. You can also integrate explicitly from $4$ to $M$, and show this blows up as $M$ gets large.

Answer (score 2):

To show it diverges formally, what if you calculate the integral $\int_4^b e^{3x} \, dx$? What happens when $b$ grows?

Intuitively, though, you can just draw the graph of $y = e^{3x}$. Is the area under the curve for the region to the right of $x = 4$ finite?